# `git gui` fails to run

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, git

I'm trying to run `git gui` in WSL Ubuntu 20.04, but it's giving me an error and failing to run:

```
$ git gui
fatal: 'gui' appears to be a git command, but we were not
able to execute it. Maybe git-gui is broken?
```

How can I get this command working?

Comment: Any feedback, @Downvoter?

Answer (score 0):

Git has GUI tools for committing (git-gui) and browsing (gitk) that can be installed from the default Ubuntu repositories. To install Git GUI in WSL use the `sudo apt install git-gui` command. To run Git GUI in WSL use the `git-gui` command.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  But I found that `git-gui` didn't exist on my system anywhere.  Once it was installed I could run it through `git gui` as I normally would.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to just be the error that is given by `git` when the `git-gui` program is missing.

(If you have it installed, it should be there somewhere like `/usr/lib/git-core/git-gui`.)

If you don't have it, you can install with the `git-gui` package:

```
sudo apt install git-gui
```

In general, the error may [apparently](https://www.madhur.co.in/blog/2014/06/08/guidebuildgit2.html) also occur if other dependencies such as `wish` are missing, but on Ubuntu `git-gui` has `tk` as a dependency, which should pull in everything needed.

Comment: Some feedback would be appreciated by the downvoter.  Is it incorrect?  Unclear?  I'm happy to fix any mistakes.